# average list of arrays within a list for each number

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

How to average this 2 list consists of array and list, i mean to get average on each number?

I tried below:
c = (a + b)/2 but results in error 'unsupported operand types'

Please help me in acheiving this like the expected output below

```
a
[array([2.945202e-02, -5.945202e-02, 7.9454265e-03],dtype=float32),
array([2.945202e-02, -5.945202e-02, 1.9454265e-03],dtype=float32),
array([2.945202e-02, -5.945202e-02, 7.9454265e-03],dtype=float32)]

b
[array([4.945202e-02, 5.945202e-02, 5.9454265e-03],dtype=float32),
array([5.945202e-02, -7.945202e-02, 6.9454265e-03],dtype=float32),
array([6.945202e-02, -8.945202e-02, 7.9454265e-03],dtype=float32)]
```

Expected output average sample format on each number (Not the right answer of above average):

```
c
[array([1.945202e-02, 2.945202e-02, 2.9454265e-03],dtype=float32),
array([5.945202e-02, -4.945202e-02, 6.9454265e-03],dtype=float32),
array([6.945202e-02, -5.945202e-02, 7.9454265e-03],dtype=float32)]
```

Comment: "(Not the right answer of above average)" Please show the right answers. Otherwise, I can't understand what the actual rule is that relates the input to the desired output.

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example and make it possible for others to use the code. Are you using Numpy? If so, then you should 1) explicitly say so; 2) indicate how you create the values, and explain exactly what things are Numpy arrays and what things are ordinary Python lists; 3) use the `numpy` tag for the question.

Comment: It *looks like* you are trying to make lists that have Numpy arrays in them. **Why**? Why not instead just use an array with one more dimension?

Comment: For output even if the results are list of list also is fine instead of array list @KarlKnechtel

Comment: these vector outputs i get it from a result which i am unable to recreate hence havenot mentioned how a and b to be created

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to find the average of `a` and `b`, you can `zip` `a` and `b` and iterate over the pairs of arrays and find the average of each:

```
avg = [(i+j)/2 for i,j in zip(a,b)]
```

Output:

```
[array([0.03945202, 0.        , 0.00694543], dtype=float32),
 array([ 0.04445202, -0.06945202,  0.00444543], dtype=float32),
 array([ 0.04945202, -0.07445202,  0.00794543], dtype=float32)]
```

or find the average using `np.mean`:

```
avg = np.mean([a, b], axis=0)
```

Output:

```
array([[ 0.03945202,  0.        ,  0.00694543],
       [ 0.04445202, -0.06945202,  0.00444543],
       [ 0.04945202, -0.07445202,  0.00794543]], dtype=float32)
```

But these answers don't match the expected output.

Comment: the former gives the right answers whereas the latter when passed to larger number it gives reduced numbers

Comment: How can i improvise this code when i need to average a,b,c,d,e,f,g variables instead of just a,b using this code ```avg = [(i+j)/2 for i,j in zip(a,b)]```

Comment: @prog `[sum(l)/len(l) for l in zip(*[a,b,c,d,e,f,g])]`.